# power series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ at $ a$

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a problem and I'm confused whether I'm doing correct or not. Problem says,

Write down a convergent power series at $a \neq 1$ which represents the function $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and find radius of convergence.

I did like, $\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{1-a-(z-a)}=\frac{1}{1-a}(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z-a}{1-a})^r)$ and thus radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{1-a}$

but if there was different power series in some ball around $a$ then couldn't be radius of convergence different from $\frac{1}{1-a}$ ?

Comment: The power series of some function around some point is unique.

Comment: ok, but how to conclude that ? should i use the fact that coefficients are given by $f^n(a)/n!$ and which is fixed in any ball around $a$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by power series at a? Mentioned power series radious of convergence is $0 \le |z| < 1$ and it converges to $1 \over {1 - z}$. This function is centered at 0.

Comment: @Trismegistos, the only power *series* written by the OP is centered at $z=a$.